# Proxy snmp v3 request to snmp v2c supported servers

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I am trying to configure Net-SNMP to accept incoming SNMP v3 requests at proxy agent and forward the requests to other internal application servers.
I have investigated and read tons of comments but I could not find how to query the proxy agent with SNMP v3 and enforce proxy agent to parse and forward this query as SNMP v2c request.

Your assistance would be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot